# Range of the function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, fractions

Let F(x)= $\frac{x^{2}-7x+10}{x^{2}-5x+6}$, then the range of f(x)
is

(a). $\mathbb{R}$

(b)$\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$

(c) $\mathbb{R}-\{3\}$

(d) none of these

Answer Sheet Says (c) is correct.

$\boldsymbol{My}$ $\boldsymbol{Approach}$$\Longrightarrow$f(x)=$\frac{(x-2)(x-5)}{(x-3(x-2)}$
{Please tell me eliminating the factors from the numerator and denominator
is a good idea or bad idea here ?}

$\Longrightarrow$$\frac{x-5}{x-3}$=1+$\frac{2}{3-x}$

x=2 $\Longrightarrow F(x)$=3 So book is wrong.So answer shoould be
(a) $\mathbb{R}$

$\boldsymbol{Help}$$\boldsymbol{I}$ $\boldsymbol{Need}$$\Longrightarrow$Please
tell me if book's answer is correct.

$\boldsymbol{I}$ $\boldsymbol{Need}$$\boldsymbol{Book}$$\boldsymbol{Suggestions}$
$\Longrightarrow$ Please suggest me books so that i can achieve a
perfection in these kind of problems.

Comment: If you assume that $x \neq 2$, then you can cancel the factor $(x-2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your work we obtain:$$\mathbb R\setminus\{3,1\}.$$
Indeed, $\frac{x-5}{x-3}\neq1$ and $\frac{x-5}{x-3}\neq3$

Comment: Please suggest me some books for the study

Comment: @Kislay Tripathi I am ready to explain. What is your question?

Comment: @Micheal Which one of the four answers is correct.eliminating factors is good idea or not

Comment: @Kislay Tripathi I think $(d)$ is correct.

Comment: @Micheal whatever    samjoe says about factor elimination is true??

Comment: @Kislay Tripathi I think the samjoe's solution was wrong.

Comment: @micheal Please suggest me a book

Comment: @Kislay Tripathi I have no any book about it. I just remember what my teacher taught  me.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $$y=\frac{x^2-7 x+10}{x^2-5 x+6}$$
wrt $x\ne 2;\;x\ne 3$ you get
$$x=\frac{3 y-5}{y-1}$$

$y\ne 1$ because this value makes zero the denominator

$y\ne 3$ because for $y=3$ would be $x=2$ that is excluded by the domain of the given function

$\dfrac{3 y-5}{y-1}=3$ has no solutions.

Thus the range is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,3\}$

Comment: please suggest me some books for this

Comment: @Raffaele For which value of $x$ we'll get $f(x)=3$?

Comment: @quasi No $y$ gives $x=3$

Comment: @quasi I corrected the answer now it's OK

Answer (score 1):

x =/= 2 since this would make the denominator of the function zero in its original form. So it is true that 3 is not in the range. However, the book is wrong too, since 1 is also not in the range; indeed, if x satisfied f(x) = 1, the numerator and denominator in the original function would be equal, but solving here leads to x = 2.

Comment: please suggest me some books for this

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\dfrac{x^{2}-7x+10}{x^{2}-5x+6}=\dfrac{(x-2)(x-5)}{(x-2)(x-3)}\rightarrow Dom(f)=\mathbb{R}-\{ 2,3\}$$
If $x\neq 2\rightarrow f^{*}(x)=\dfrac{x-5}{x-3}=\dfrac{x-3-2}{x-3}=1-\dfrac{2}{x-3}$
$$f^{*}(2)=3; \dfrac{x^{2}-7x+10}{x^{2}-5x+6}=3\rightarrow x^{2}-7x+10=3x^{2}-15x+18\rightarrow$$
$$2x^{2}-8x+8=0\rightarrow x^{2}-4x+4=0\rightarrow x=2\notin Dom(f)\rightarrow \nexists x,\hspace{2mm} \text{for}\hspace{2mm} y=3$$
Also, $1-\dfrac{2}{x-3}=y\rightarrow \dfrac{2}{x-3}=1-y\rightarrow x-3=\dfrac{2}{1-y}\rightarrow \nexists x,\hspace{2mm} \text{for}\hspace{2mm} y=1$

As $\lim_{x\to 3^{-}}f(x)=+\infty\hspace{2mm} \wedge \lim_{x\to 3^{+}}f(x)=-\infty\rightarrow Rec(f)=\mathbb{R}-\{ 1,3\}$

Answer (score 0):

since $$x^2-5x+6=(x-2)(x-3)$$ you will have $$x\ne 2$$ and $$x\neq 3$$
since $$f(x)=\frac{(x-2)(x-5)}{(x-2)(x-3)}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)$$ exists you can define
$$f(x)=\frac{x-5}{x-3}$$ if $x\ne 2$ and $$f(x)=3$$ if $x=2$

Comment: please suggest me some books for this